# How can I log key presses using turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, coding-efficiency

I'm trying to make a simple turtle script that asks the user for their username, and then stores that. I don't have any code, but if I used onkeypress, it seems I would have to make a function for appending every single possible character to the username variable, and that doesn't seem very pythonic. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

> if I used onkeypress, it seems I would have to make a function for
>   appending every single possible character to the username variable,
>   and that doesn't seem very pythonic. Is there a better way to do this?

Yes but no.  If you leave off the second, `key`, argument to the turtle's `onkeypress()` function, it will call your key press handler code when *any* key is pressed.  Problem is, they left off the code to let you know which key!

We can work around this design error by rewriting the underlying `_onkeypress` code to pass tkinter's `event.char` to the turtle's event handler in the case where no key has been set (i.e. `key is None`).

Here's a crude example of this to get you started:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from functools import partial

FONT = ('Arial', 18, 'normal')

def _onkeypress(self, fun, key=None):
    if fun is None:
        if key is None:
            self.cv.unbind("<KeyPress>", None)
        else:
            self.cv.unbind("<KeyPress-%s>" % key, None)
    elif key is None:
        def eventfun(event):
            fun(event.char)
        self.cv.bind("<KeyPress>", eventfun)
    else:
        def eventfun(event):
            fun()
        self.cv.bind("<KeyPress-%s>" % key, eventfun)

def letter(character):
    turtle.write(character, move=True, font=FONT)

turtle = Turtle()

screen = Screen()
screen._onkeypress = partial(_onkeypress, screen)
screen.onkeypress(letter)
screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

Just start typing at the window and your characters will show up.  You'll need to handle *special* characters (e.g. *return*) yourself.