# Python turtle: trigger function on any key pressed

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

How can I add random key pressed with `turtle` (that means that I don't want this:`scr.onkey(fun,'r'`)?

I tried this...

```
import turtle as system

scr=system.Screen()

def p():
     print('button pressed')

scr.onkey(p,any)
```

...but this does not work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Just supply "None", or omit the parameter altogether.

Comment: @TimRoberts, `onkey()` will generate errors if you supply `None` or omit the parameter.  See @rdas answer about `onkeypress()`, or my answer for an explanation.

Comment: I tried this...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a complete example -- note that you were also not showing the `listen()` method in your code fragment which is also required:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def handler():
    turtle.write("Button pressed!", align='center', font=('Arial', 18, 'normal'))

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()

screen.onkeypress(handler)

screen.listen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Here's the story:  The `onkey()` method is also known as `onkeyrelease()` and neither accepts `None` as a character, nor a missing character argument.  @TimRoberts comment won't work.  As @rdas notes (+1), use the `onkeypress()` method which does accept a `None` character, or simply a missing argument, and does what you want.

But here's a catch:  Your event handler will trigger on any key, but you've no means within Turtle to determine *which* key.  If you need that functionality, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59914207/5771269) which provides a replacement `onkeypress()` method that passes the character typed to your event handler, in the case where a character was not specified.  (I.e. the `None` case.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`onkeypress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.onkeypress) instead.

```
scr.onkeypress(p)
```

The `key` argument, if not given, will trigger the function for any key press.

> Bind fun to key-press event of key if key is given, or to any key-press-event if no key is given.